# TikZ Angle Label - Help it "fit" better?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I have the following drawn with TikZ

[image]

using the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw (O) circle (3);
\coordinate[label = above left:$M$] (M) at (130:3);
\coordinate[label = above:$N$] (N) at (80:3);
\coordinate[label = below:$A$] (A) at (240:3);
\coordinate[label =below right:$B$] (B) at (300:3);
\draw (A) -- (M) -- (B);
\draw (A) -- (N) -- (B);
\tkzMarkAngle[draw = black, fill = white, opacity=1](A,M,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.8](A,M,B){$x$}
\tkzMarkAngle[pos = 0.2,draw = black, fill = white, opacity=1](A,N,B)
\tkzLabelAngle [pos=0.8](A,N,B){$27 ^{\circ}$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Notice however, tht the 27 degrees does not fit in very nicely. How can I adapt the code to try and move the 27 a bit "lower" so that it fits in better, as well as the angle mark?

Also, how can I get two "double arrows" in the middle of lines AM and BN, to indicate that they are 'parallel'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Use `size=<length>` for `\tkzMarkAngle` to control the radius for the arc used for the mark.
2. Use the `pos` key in `\tkzLabelAngle` to move the label away (or closer) to the vertex of the angle.

   - You could also try reducing a little the font size:

     ```
     \tkzMarkAngle[size=1.3,draw = black, fill = white, opacity=1](A,N,B)
     \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.1,font=\scriptsize](A,N,B){$27 ^{\circ}$}
     ```
3. Although tkz-euclide provides `\tkzMarkSegments` to place marks on segments, I opted below for a decoration using arrows, to draw the two sets of arrows to represent parallelism.
4. Your lines AM and BN are not parallels. I provided some code below to get real parallel lines (in the edit history of this answer there's a version with the original non-parallel lines).

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\tikzset{
  middlearrows/.style={
    decoration={             
      markings, 
      mark=at position 0.48 with {\arrow{triangle 45};},
      mark=at position 0.52 with {\arrow{triangle 45};}
      },
  postaction={decorate}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label = above left:$M$] (M) at (130:3);
\coordinate[label = above:$N$] (N) at (80:3);
\coordinate[label = below:$A$] (A) at (240:3);

% parallel to MA passing through N
\tkzDefLine[parallel=through N](M,A)
\tkzGetPoint{Aux}
% Intersections between the parallel and the circle
\tkzInterLC(N,Aux)(O,M)
\tkzGetPoints{N}{B}
\tkzLabelPoints(B)

\tkzDrawSegments(M,B N,A)

\tkzMarkAngle[draw = black, fill = white, opacity=1](A,M,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.8](A,M,B){$x$}

\tkzMarkAngle[size=1.4,draw = black, fill = white, opacity=1](A,N,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.15,font=\scriptsize](A,N,B){$27 ^{\circ}$}

\draw[middlearrows] (A) -- (M); 
\draw[middlearrows] (B) -- (N); 

\tkzDrawCircle[R](O,3cm)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! :). I am setting up a mathematics test paper in which I had to include the diagram for a question - the picture is not drawn to scale (which is why it may not appear that AM and BN are parallels) :) . The arrows that you used are perfect :) . I just needed something to indicate to the students that those two lines must be seen as parallel (in order to prove some things in later questions) . :) . Also, thank you for not just showing me "how" to do it, but also providing a nice explanation as to what each parameter does :). It really helped a great deal.

Comment: @DJS You're welcome! I suspected the non parallel drawing was on purpose but wasn't sure :) As a side note, don't forget that you can accept the answers that you consider solved your problems :)